# Spring error converting nvarchar to bigint

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion, varchar, bigint

I'm getting an error whenever I try to save an object.

The field causing the error is a `string` mapped to a `varchar(200)` in the database.
The name of the field is `localContact`.

Here's my code:

**Site.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SITE", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "SITE_COUNTRY_ID", "SITE_NAME" }) })
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, withModifiedFlag = true)
public class Site implements ISite {

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -390717603276436784L;

/** The id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SITE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

/** The site address. */
@Column(name = "SITE_ADDRESS", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_ADDRESS)
private String address;

/** The site analog phone number. */
@Column(name = "SITE_ANALOG_PHONE_NUMBER", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_ANALOG_PHONE_NUMBER)
private String analogPhoneNumber;

/** The site comment. */
@Column(name = "SITE_COMMENT", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_COMMENT)
private String comment;

/** The site entity code. */
@Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0, message = "Please enter max 3 digits")
@Column(name = "SITE_ENTITY_CODE", nullable = false)
private long entityCode;

/** The site invoice code. */
@Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 0, message = "Please enter max 10 digits")
@Column(name = "SITE_INVOICE_CODE", nullable = false)
private long invoiceCode;

/** The site local it phone. */
@Column(name = "SITE_LOCAL_IT_PHONE", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_LOCAL_IT_PHONE)
private String localItPhone;

/** The site name. */
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "SITE_NAME", nullable = false, length = BusinessConstants.SITE_NAME)
private String siteName;

/** The site subnet. */
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "SITE_SUBNET", nullable = false, length = BusinessConstants.SITE_SUBNET)
private String subnet;

/** The site user number. */
@Digits(integer = 4, fraction = 0, message = "Please enter max 4 digits")
@Column(name = "SITE_USER_NUMBER")
private Long userNumber;

/** The business. */
@Valid
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_BUSINESS_ID", nullable = false)
private Business business;

/** The country. */
@Valid
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_COUNTRY_ID")
private Country country;

/** The local contact. */
@Column(name = "SITE_LOCAL_CONTACT", nullable = true, length = BusinessConstants.LOCAL_CONTACT)
private String localContact; //the field that cause the error

/** The local it. */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_LOCAL_IT", nullable = true)
private User localIt;

/** The rif. */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_RIF", nullable = true)
private User rif;

/** The status. */
@Valid
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_STATUS_ID", nullable = false)
private Status status;

/** The end date. */
@Column(name = "SITE_END_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
private Date endDate = null;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "userSites", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotAudited
private Set<IUser> siteUsers;

/**
 * Gets the local contact.
 *
 * @return the local contact
 */
public String getLocalContact() {
    return this.localContact;
}

/**
 * Sets the local contact.
 *
 * @param localIt the new local contact
 */
public void setLocalContact(String localContact) {
    this.localContact = localContact;
}
```

my jsp :

```
<td class="label"><spring:message code="site.localcontact" /></td>
        <td class="value">
            <form:input path="site.localContact"></form:input>
        </td>
```

my DAO:

```
public void saveSite(ISite siteObj){
    Assert.notNull(siteObj);
    merge((Site) siteObj);
}
```

**EDIT**

The error being thrown is:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: @LaurentiuL. Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: Somewhere along the lines, a string is being parsed to a bigint column. I suspect you haven't matched  the datatypes properly. Try sp_help,  sp_helptable on the db table. I think you can use the columnn as string, but you must ensure it has a number. Otherwise, change the type. But do post the table description

Comment: @Laurentiu L. the type is varchar(200) according to sp_help

Comment: How can you be sure the field local contact is causing it? I don't see it in the error message.

Comment: cause before I change the field type in DB from bigint to varchar there was no problem

Comment: That may be so, and yet a conversion is happening on one of your fields. And it's not a number. I suggest you fiddle with the fields you send one by one until you pinpoint. You may start with the one you think is causing the problem.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. done. when i comment the line "site.setLocalContact(siteRequest.getLocalContact());" in my code there is no error, so I'm sure that the error come from here

Comment: It is possible the change you applied to the field type in DB from bigint to varchar is not being taken into account. It's hard to pinpoint exactly with little detail. Try checking the db schema you are using is actually the one you are expecting and so on. Also, you should share the script you ran on the table to change the type.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. I found the error, I posted an answer. Thank you for your help and time spent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error,

I have another table making an historic of my SITE named SITE_AUD and the field SITE_LOCAL_CONTACT in it was a bigint.